# $(window).scroll fires after touch on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am updating some css has the window scrolls. This works well on desktop as the scroll event is in action.

However on mobile the scroll event fires after the touch causing the screen to jump.

Is there a touch event that would cover both?

```
$(window).scroll(function() {         
   scrollBanner();        
});

function scrollBanner() {
  //Get the scoll position of the page
  scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

  //Scroll and fade out the banner text
  $('#bannerText').css({
    'margin-bottom' : -(scrollPos/3)+"px",
    'opacity' : 1-(scrollPos/300)
  });

}
```

Comment: For performance reasons, scroll should be implemented with `setInterval`. There are many answers for that here in SO, but I don't have the link at hand.

Comment: Depending on the device (and the browser and DOM and whatever else) touch events are fired in an order like `touchstart, touchmove, touchend, [click], [scroll]` - so checking for scroll changes in an interval would work, or checking on `touchmove` might also work. The interval method is a little more fool-proof in case an object on you page (video, for example) is canceling the `touchmove` event but the user is still scrolling.

Comment: thanks Arturo for the advice. I will look into that.